# Why does AngularJS log an object, although it is not injected inside the function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have unexpected behavior from my AngularJS application.

Why is john logged, although it is not injected inside the logPerson() function?

```js
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []);

var Person = function(firstname, lastname) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
}

function logPerson() {
  console.log(john);
}

var john = new Person('John', 'Doe');

logPerson();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="angularApp">
    <head>
        <title>Introduction to AngularJS</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <!-- load angular via CDN -->
        <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js">             
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you call logPerson john is already in the global scope

Comment: JavaScript has lexical scope. A function can access any variable that exists inside its own and in its parent's scope. `john` is defined in the parent scope of `logPerson`. Also the function body is only evaluated when the function is called, at which point `john` has been assigned a value.

Answer (score 1):

The `john` variable is already declared, initialised and in scope before the `logPerson()` function is being called. This is not anything Angular.js specific, it's how JavaScript runtime engines work.

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant hoisting is in this regard. What matters is that the variable exist at the moment `logPerson` is called that is the case with or without hoisting.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It's even simpler than what I thought.